# What's happened when await variable which has type Task

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I create a Task variable and try to await it just for learning purposes with the next code:

```
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start");
            Task myTask = new Task(() => { Console.WriteLine("Done"); });
            await myTask;
            Console.WriteLine("Finish");
        }
```

Application writes Start in the console and then it freezes. I am not sure how to understand whats happened here and why does it freeze. What can be the reason?

I know that usually we apply await to the methods which return Task, but not variable. But vs compiles such code successfully. The expectation was to get all 3 messages in the console.

Comment: Add `myTask.Start();`

Comment: Don't use such code in the first place. Tasks aren't threads and `await` *awaits*, it doesn't start tasks. There's seldom any good reason to create cold tasks. If you have something that really needs to run in the background use `Task.Run` or `await Task.Run()`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos *"Tasks aren't threads"* -- Where did the OP said that tasks are threads?

Comment: Nitpicking aside, it's clear the OP thought that creating a task would result in some kind of execution. This is similar to several dozen identical questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new Task()` creates a new task instance, but does not start it.

so your task never runs, and never has a chance to finish. to fix it you, have to start it first:

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start");
    Task myTask = new Task(() => { Console.WriteLine("Done"); });

    myTask.Start();

    await myTask;
    Console.WriteLine("Finish");
}
```

i also recommend reading [Microsofts Tutorial on tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Even better: `myTask.Start(TaskScheduler.Default);`, so that the task is executed on a well known scheduler. Check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2008) reliability rule for more details.

Comment: Or even better yet, use `Task.Run`

Comment: There's seldom any good reason to use `new Task` unless you write low-level library code, like that found in the .NET Core runtime. Tasks aren't threads and `Task.Run` doesn't guarantee that something will start executing immediatelly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, as stated in the docs!

Answer (score 1):

[Do not ever use the `Task` constructor](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html) (link is to my blog). There are literally *zero* use cases for it that aren't achieved by better means.

If you want to start work running on the thread pool, then use `Task.Run`:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Start");
  Task myTask = Task.Run(() => { Console.WriteLine("Done"); });
  await myTask;
  Console.WriteLine("Finish");
}
```